# Cambiar los puntos a diferentes colores en Matplotlib, python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando con un dataset que contiene 3 columnas, necesitaba graficar las 2 primeras, y en la tercer columna tenía las etiquetas correspondientes a las primeras dos columnas.

El caso es que pude graficar las 2 columnas pero ahora necesito colorear los puntos correspondientes a sus etiquetas, intenté de algunas formas que vi en internet pero simplemente no pude implementarlo en mi código

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
colores = ["#00cc44",  # Verde

           "#ff0000"   # Rojo
           ]
#
df = pd.df = pd.read_csv(
    "C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Machine learning\\segmentation1.csv", header=None)
datos = np.array(df)

# creando los arreglos x y donde se contendran las columnas 0 y 1

x = []
y = []
k = []
i = 0
# separando la columna 0 que se encontraba en datos
columnaX = [fila[i] for fila in datos]
x.append(columnaX)

j = 1
columnaY = [filaY[j] for filaY in datos]
y.append(columnaY)

l = 2

columnaK = [filaK[l] for filaK in datos]
k.append(columnaK)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=30, c=np.take(colores, k))
plt.show()
[![Esta es la grafica resultante, necesito que cada uno de esos puntos tengan el color que le corresoponde, las etiquetas las tengo dentro de la misma base de datos(-1 y 1) son sus etiquetas respectivas][1]][1]
```

Separé las etiquetas en "k", tenía planeado usarla como algún parámetro o algo si era posible para hacer que cada punto se pintara de acuerdo a esta columna.

[image: Los errores que salen]

Comment: Puedes poner la traza de error por favor. Así podremos saber que está ocurriendo exactamente :)

Comment: Hola claro esta estos son los errores que me aparecen

Comment: `plt.plot(x[0:29], y[0:29], "xr")
plt.plot(x[30:59], y[30:59], "ob")`     tambien intente mostarlo asi separandolos manualmente pero al momento de mostrar la grafica solo se colorea conforme a la primera linea, entonces toda la grafica queda de color rojo

Comment: `columnaX = [fila[i] for fila in datos]
x = matrix(columnaX)

j = 1
columnaY = [filaY[j] for filaY in datos]
y = matrix(columnaY)`   tambien hice este cambio a los arreglos haciendolos un arreglo de numpy